# How would three level tens fare against a CR 14 False Hydra

Tags: dnd-5e, one-shot

I'm currently writing a one-shot adventure to run with my friends that has a false hydra as the final boss. I found the stat sheet for it [here](https://www.gmbinder.com/share/-LAoJ_bfNWBTTmIV9KQ_). I'm planning on using the adult form with only three heads. Do you think that this thing is beatable with this party? Or will I need to bump it down a notch?

Comment: What classes/races are they? That will make a big difference to their ability to win. And this question is highly opinion based, which means it will probably be closed. But that's OK, maybe find a better way to word the question if that happens.

Comment: And try this link: https://www.gmbinder.com/share/-LAoJ_bfNWBTTmIV9KQ_. If you follow the one above, the last underscore (_) is being left off

Comment: Please include essential stats in the question. Link may rot and become dead (content no longer accessible), or owner of the site may change it,

Comment: We need to knnow more about your group and the terrain.

Comment: This creature explains neatly why I never use someone else's homebrew.

Comment: looks like a spot of plagiarism.  http://goblinpunch.blogspot.com/2014/09/false-hydra.html - be wary, though.  That thing eats *towns*.

Comment: In addition to classes/races, how much do they know about this creature?  Are they expecting, preparing, and/or designing their characters specfically to fight this creature?  Are they surprised by it?  These possibilities create a huge spectrum of difficulties.  Though 5e isn't as bad about this as 3.5e (not the least reason being bounded accuracy), [here](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~dkb1/dnd/tarrasque.txt) are several case studies in how a single level 13 character can defeat one of the toughest 3.5e monsters that typically requires a party of 20's

Answer (score 2):

**This is a TPK waiting to happen**

OK, without knowing the party composition, I think I can say this thing is brutal.

The hit points combined with the number of attacks it can make (let's assume 3 heads) makes it a huge damage dealer.
If it has three heads, it can attack with it's bite 3 times and use a legendary action at the start of each player's turn for 6 bites in a round for an average of 138 damage per round, and that is ignoring the additional grapple damage.
And that doesn't even account for the legendary resistances, the sonic blast and the risk of being engulfed.

And it could always cast *Dominate Monster* to take a player out of the fight...

You might want to tone it down a smidge.

Comment: This looks like it’s at least a CR 18.

Comment: The False Hydra is *so* much worse than that.  You clearly didn't read Mindsong thoroughly.

Comment: @BenBarden I reread the feature, which is terribly written, and it seems like fighting this thing is nearly impossible *for anyone*.